# Save to Database action missing in Web Forms for Marketers 2.5

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have installed Web Forms for Marketers 2.5 in new instance of Sitecore 7.5 and I don't see "Save to Database" action in new version. Also there is no MDF file in version I believe this is because new version uses MongoDB. There is a WFFM_Analytics.sql not sure in which DB I need to use to run this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Reporting" database is not attached to the DB server by default when you initially install Sitecore 7.5 (at least not with SIM).

Per [Sitecore 7.5 Installation Guidelines](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/installation_guide_sc75-a4.pdf) - Section 6.2:

> **Configuring the reporting database** – attach the *Sitecore.Analytics.mdf* database to
> SQL Server. This database is used for reporting.
>
> o In the ConnectionStrings.config file, customize the following string:

```
<add name="reporting" connectionString="user id=_username_;password=_password_;Data Source=_server_;Database=Sitecore_Analytics" />
```

**Note:** You can find the Sitecore_Analytics database under the [site root]\Database folder

Once you have attached the reporting database and updated the connection string, you will need to run the sql file as mentioned int he package installer instructions.  (see Brad's answer).

You are correct that the 'Save to Database' action is no there anymore.  I'll try to see if the data is saved automatically or if a Save to Database action was missed while packaging when I get some time later tonight.

Comment: Configured reporting DB and ran the sql file, still I don't see "save to database" action and no records in form report.

Comment: looks like data is saved automatically in Web Forms for Marketers 2.5, I can see the results in report next day after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps from within the package installer?

> Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers installation.
>
> Post installation steps:
>
> 1. The "Restricting Placeholders" application will offer 
>      you to define the set of placeholders where your forms 
>      can be added.
> 2. Republish content to the "web" database.
> 3. In the [site root]\Website\Data find WFFM_Analytics.sql and run it on the reporting db of your current instance.
>      This will create 3 additional tables in your reporting db.
> 4. Add the following nodes to the Web.config:
>
>    - for IIS 6.x under the configuration\system.web\httpHandlers node
>    - for IIS 7.x and up under the configuration\system.webServer\handlers node

See also [Web Forms for Marketers v2.5 User Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/25/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_5%20user%20guide-a4.pdf)

And, "reporting db" should be your `/Databases/MDF/<instance>Sitecore.Analytics.mdf` database.

Answer (score 0):

In WFFM 2.5 in sitecore 7.5 the data will be saved automatically to MongoDB after the session end the data will be transferred to SQL database.